# Is there a way to import a python helper library from a deployed Google Cloud Function, outside the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We are developing an application on Google Cloud that makes use of Cloud Functions in Python. We're looking at developing a generic helper library that many of our functions will import.

The problem with this is if the helper library is changed in any way, all our functions will need to be redeployed.

I'm trying to find a way to host (for want of a better word) our helper library (for example in Google Cloud Storage), and somehow import it into the `main.py` files, such that any changes to the helper library can be made without having to redeploy the functions. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported with the provided tools. You can only invoke code that was deployed with the function.  There is no "dynamic" loading of code over the internet.

Also, in my opinion, this is a pretty bad idea, because your functions could break in a very profound way if there's a problem during loading of the remote code, or you accidentally (or someone maliciously) push something wrong.  You're going to be better off getting all your code and libraries together at once, test it all at once, and deploy it all at once.

You're free to try to implement something yourself, but I strongly advise against it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Makes perfect sense.